# How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan{x} - \sin{x}}{x(1 - \cos{x})}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan{x} - \sin{x}}{x(1 - \cos{x})}$ ?

The limit is of the form $0/0$, so I thought we can apply L'hopital. But the limit of the derivatives is also $0/0$, and the limit of the second derivatives is also $0/0$. Is there something else we need to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{\tan{x} - \sin{x}}{x(1 - \cos{x})}=\frac {\sin x} x\frac {\frac 1 {\cos x}-1} {1-\cos x}=\frac {\sin x} x \frac 1 {\cos x}$ so the limit is $1$.

Comment: How did you guess that $\frac{1/\cos{x} - 1}{1 - \cos{x}} = \frac{1}{\cos{x}}$ ? It wasn't obvious to me

Comment: $\frac 1 y -1=\frac {1-y} y$. @wengen

Comment: But in this case, don't we have a product of two limits ? I mean $\sin{x}/x$ and $1/\cos{x}$. Can we apply L'hopital for $\sin{x}/x$ if it's multiplied by another fraction that depends on $x$ right next to it ?

Comment: $\lim [f(x)g(x)]=\lim f(x) \lim g(x)$ if both limits exist. @wengen

Answer (score 1):

By L'hopital:
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{x(1-\cos(x))}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sec^2(x)-\cos(x)}{1-\cos(x)+x\sin(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2\sec^2(x)\tan(x)+\sin(x)}{x\cos(x)+2\sin(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-4\sec^2(x)+6\sec^4(x)+\cos(x)}{-x\sin(x)+3\cos(x)}=\frac{-4+6+1}{-0+3}=\frac{3}{3}=1\blacksquare
\end{align}